# Unity Facebook SDK: post screenshot to wall not working

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 4.5, the latest facebook sdk 6.0 and I am working on android right now but it should also work on iOS. 
I am trying to take a screenshot and upload it to my wall, therefore I use the standard example scene from the facebook sdk.
Everything works fine when I use my private account as a test account, and it also works with the facebook app ID's of older projects (at least 1 year old). But with a normal account (no tester) and a new facebook app it is not working.

Do I have to do a full submission to use the "post an image to the users wall" function or am I doing something wrong?
My facebook app says "This app is public and available to all users" . So I guess it should work right?

I use this for login:

```
private void CallFBLogin()
{
    FB.Login("email, publish_actions", LoginCallback);
}

 void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
        lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
    else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        lastResponse = "Login cancelled by Player";
    }
    else
    {
        lastResponse = "Login was successful!";
    }
}
```

And this as screenshot method:

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    textureTest = tex;

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");
    wwwForm.AddField("message", "herp derp.  I did a thing!  Did I do this right?");

    FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);
}
```

Hope someone has a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-publish_actions). You need to submit your app for review if you require the `publish_actions` permission.

> **Review**
>
> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to
>   review how your app uses it.
>
> When requesting this permission via App Review, please make sure your
>   instructions are easily reproducible by our team.